# What is the difference in meaning between "choice" and "option"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions

When must we use *option* but not *choice*, and where do we use *choice* but not *option*?

Or can we use them interchangeably always?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options are spread before us to choose.

For example, you won a competition and the prizes are
1. A car
2. A Bike
3. An LED TV
These are the options and what you decide to take is upto your choice.

Options are the things and choices are our decision.
Options are fixed and choices aren't.

In other words, option is a noun for a thing and choice is a noun for your decision.
They can both be used as verbs "to choose" and "to opt", but to say "I opt" is quiet rare.

Comment: But the phrases "I opt in" (or "I opt out") is fairly common in the US, probably becasue it is much shorter than "I choose to be included".

Comment: @bib "opt in/out" is also common in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have three islands: (A), (B), and (C). Draw a line between them to signify paths like so:

```
    (A)
   /   \
  (B) (C)
```

You start at (A). Your 'choices' are represented by the lines between (A) to (B) and (A) to (C). There is no choice (no line) to go from (B) to (C) because you start at (A). While (B) and (C) are both 'options' of where you go.